# EXCEL: Formula for looking up values and corresponding values

Tags: excel

I have an issue with excel. My data is located in 2 different spread sheets.

The sheets are login and events:

**LOGIN**

user_id  (COL A)

signup_date (COL B)

**EVENTS**

user_id (COL A)

end_date (COL B)

revenue (COL C)

I am trying to find the average days from a user signing up to their first event ending.
In trying to match the user ids, I have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
=MIN(IF(A2=Events!$A$2:$A$12282,(Events!B$2:B$12282)-B2))
```

In this case, for each user in login, i am trying to find the corresponding dates in Events that match with that user. Then I am trying to find the difference in dates and find the minimum one in the array, but it is giving the max value instead and/or not working. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your formula will certainly not work. Can a user have different rows in LOGIN? In other words, can the same user have different sign_up dates?

Comment: Cross posted [on SU](http://superuser.com/q/638347/219090).

Answer (score 0):

The `DMIN` function will work (though I find the functionality to be a bit clunky to work with).  If you wanted to use `DMIN`, you can do the following.

Create a 3rd worksheet and create three column headers in cells `A1` & `B1`.  `A1` should contain `user_id`.  `B1` can be something like `minimum_event_date`.  `C1` can be something like `delta_date`.

In cell `A2` enter this formula:

```
="="&Login!A2
```

In cell `B2` enter this formula:

```
=DMIN(Events!$A$1:$B$37,"end_date",A$1:A2)
```

You will need to change `Events!$A$1:$B$37` to match the data range from your `Events` sheet.

In cell `C2` enter this formula:

```
=B2-Login!B2
```

You can then fill the columns down until all of your users from the `Login` sheet are shown in the 3rd worksheet.  This will return the minimum date from your `Events` worksheet for each `user_id` listed on the `Login` sheet

Answer (score 0):

On the Login sheet I would add one more column `days_to_first_event`. And in C2 add the following array formula (press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to set it)

```
=MIN(IF(tbl_events[user_id]=A2,tbl_events[end_date]))-B2
```

This finds the earliest `end_date` for the `user_id` on the `Events` sheet, then subtracts the user's `signup_date`. (I've formatted them as a table called `tbl_events` but you can substitute for your range)

Then you can average based on positive values, as anything negative would mean that they have not completed an event yet. Using this formula

```
=SUMIF(C:C,">=0")/COUNTIF(C:C,">=0")
```

It's possible to contain all of that in one formula, but I can't wrap my brain around that this morning.